# error with gtkmm 3 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compiler-errors, gtkmm

i install libgtkmm-3.0-dev in ubuntu 12.04 and i try to learn and write program with c++ and gtkmm 3 
i go to this link "http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-basics-simple-example.html.en" and try to compile simple example program :

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app =
    Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,
      "org.gtkmm.examples.base");

  Gtk::ApplicationWindow window;

  return app->run(window);
}
```

my file name is "basic.cc" and i open terminal and type following command to compile:

```
g++ basic.cc -o basic `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

compile completed without any error but when i try to run program with type ./basic in terminal i get following error :

```
~$ ./simple
./simple: symbol lookup error: ./simple: undefined symbol:_ZN3Gtk11Application6createERiRPPcRKN4Glib7ustringEN3Gio16ApplicationFlagsE
~$
```

how can i solve this problem ?

i can cimpile any gtkmm 2.4 code with this command : " g++ basic.cc -o basic `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` " 
and this command : " g++ basic.cc -o basic `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags --libs` "

thanks

Comment: Could you paste the output of the following commands?
  `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --libs`
  `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --modversion`

Comment: no , i paste the output of this commands : g++ basic.cc -o basic `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`

Comment: I am not getting your exact error, but I am getting a Seg Fault with the same code from developer.gnome.org, so it seem there might be an issue somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you hit this gtkmm bug, apparently triggered by more recent versions of GTK+, and now fixed:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=681323

I have asked Ubuntu to update their package, but they are usually slow about that if they do it at all:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtkmm3.0/+bug/1046469

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try reinstalling libgtkmm-3.0-dev. The code compiles fine for me but I get a Seg Fault. It does work when I change `Gtk::ApplicationWindow` to `Gtk::Window`.

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with your install.  that code is bad.

try it again, using

```
Gtk::Window window;
```

instead of the ApplicationWindow.  When the [GNOME documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1ApplicationWindow.html) for a given class has a description of "TODO", that's a bad thing.

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with his code. He just hit a bug in gtkmm and it's not his fault.

Comment: i got an error with his code as well.  it would compile, but would crash at runtime.  replacing with Window seemed to work fine.  but if you found the bug, that's great.  hopefully they will put it in the next build.  as far as a solution goes, using Window should work for now.

Comment: and i should've used better wording.  by "code is bad", i meant that the underlying gtk code is bad, and from the looks of it, changing his install isn't going to work well until the patch is applied.  his code was a normal example, and was fine.  but even in the bug link you provided, the suggestion was to change the turotial/example code to use Window.